# Looking to test iPhone 5C tint colors. Is this available in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, tintcolor

I'm looking to test how my app looks on the various iPhone 5C colors.  I don't see an option to enable the tints in the iOS simulator.  Is there a way to do this?  If not, has anyone heard that it is a forthcoming feature in XCode?

Comment: Not available. File a feature enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: Thanks Leo.  Submitted request to Apple Jan 10, 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tint of the device casing is not available (publicly) via software, this functionality you're after is not possible. Report an enhancement request via http://bugreport.apple.com